# java.math.BigDecimal division inaccuracy

Tags: java, kotlin, bigdecimal

In Kotlin, BigDecimal division returns strange results.

```
BigDecimal(1.0) / BigDecimal(2.0)
// returns 0.0
// Just like Int(1) / Int(2) returns 0
```

But:

```
BigDecimal(1.1) / BigDecimal(2.0)
// returns 0.55
// Just like Double(1.1) / Double(2.0) returns 0.55
```

So why does that happen and how can I make `1.0 / 2.0` returns 0.5 with BigDecimal without using `divide()` giving a scale parameter?

UPDATES:

Here are the complete codes:

```
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.41 (JRE 1.8.0_172-b11)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> import java.math.BigDecimal
>>> BigDecimal(1.0) / BigDecimal(2.0)
0
>>> BigDecimal(1.1) / BigDecimal(2.0)
0.550000000000000044408920985006261616945266723632812
```

UPDATES 2:

According to @user2864740

```
BigDecimal(1.0).divide(BigDecimal(2.0))
// returns 0.5
```

and

```
BigDecimal("1.0") / BigDecimal(2.0)
// returns 0.5
```

So the results are confusing. For BigDecimals, why do `1.0 / 2.0` returns 0.0, `1.0.divide(2.0)` returns 0.5, and `"1.0" / 2.0` returns 0.5?

Comment: "Works In Standard Java (TM)" - https://repl.it/repls/OutlyingUnusualProducts (how is Kotlin and/or the setup different?)

Comment: Note that it works if you use the string constructor: https://ideone.com/qqyV0c

Comment: @user2864740 Well for starts, it's a different language.

Comment: @mypetlion It's the same java.math.BigDecimal class, no? So, a mostly non-interesting reply. A more interesting reply would be some thing like `print` "does such and such magic" or "Kotlin is calling a different constructor" or "/" in Kotlin is not calling the `divide` method.. or whatever is *really* occurring. It's this *interesting / relevant / focused* information that should make it into answers.

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't post an answer. My point was that if the question is about kotlin, and your request for clarifying information is essentially "What's kotlin", then maybe just don't bother.

Comment: @mypetlion And you *did* post a snarky comment. Do note how a "comment from someone who doesn't know Kotlin" supplied the reasoning in one of three presented hypothesis.. the issue with a "it's a different language" without qualification is it is dismisses the fact that Kotlin works on rules, many of which are shared with a multitude of other languages, including Java. This is especially so when the same underlying runtime/types are used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you write [`divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)) explicitly, it will work the same way as it does in Java:

```
val a = BigDecimal(1.0)
val b = BigDecimal(2.0)
val x = a.divide(b) // 0.5
```

When you use the `/` operator, that translates to the [`BigDecimal.div`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/div.html) extension from the standard library, which does the following:

> Enables the use of the / operator for BigDecimal instances.
>
> The scale of the result is the same as the scale of this (divident), and for rounding the RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN rounding mode is used.

You can take a look at how the different `RoundingMode` constants work [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Comment: It has something to do with scale specifically. It works if you do `BigDecimal("1.0")` or `BigDecimal(1.0).setScale(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

`1.1` is a `double` literal

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Therefore by the time the value is passed to `BigDecimal` you already lost precision due to the `double` value. `BigDecimal(1.1)` is equivalent to `double d = 1.1; BigDecimal(d)`. You need to pass the value as string

```
BigDecimal("1.1")
```

unless the value is exactly representable as a double like `1.5`

Comment: There's no precision loss: `BigDecimal(1.0) == BigDecimal("1")`

Comment: @shmosel I mean `1.1`

Comment: The question was about `1.0`.

Comment: the question was about 1.1, and it still is `BigDecimal(1.1) / BigDecimal(2.0)`